# Cannot make a breakpoint in my mini debugger for linux

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, ptrace

I work on making a mini debugger as a personal project. the debugger is for x86 processors under GNU/Linux environment.

In my approach of setting a breakpoint at a specific address of the debugged program works for the first time i lunch my debugger. if i try it again it fails.

I want to make sure if i do this in a right way.

suppose i have a helloworld program to be debugged as following:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cerr << "hello,World\n";
return 0;
}
```

and it is dissembled with **objdump -d** as following

```
0000000000400907 <main>:
400907: 55                      push   %rbp
  400908:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40090b:   be 04 0a 40 00          mov    $0x400a04,%esi
  400910:   bf 60 10 60 00          mov    $0x601060,%edi
  400915:   e8 06 ff ff ff          callq  400820 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
  40091a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40091f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400920:   c3                      retq
```

and for sure i compiled my helloworld with **-g** option.

for the first trial, i was setting a breakpoint at **0x400915** and at **0x40091a** . so what i was expecting is that when i **continue**(the command like GDB) my debugger, it will stop at **0x400915** and when i **continue** again it will print "helloworld" but non of that happened. it just go to the return as there was no any breakpoints.

So as another trial, when my debugger starts my helloworld program. i see the pid of helloworld program and open its **maps** file at /proc/[helloworld pid]/maps which looks like

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1578540                            /home/yahia/mytinydebugger/tdbg/build/debugging-examples/helloworld
00600000-00602000 rw-p 00000000 08:07 1578540                            /home/yahia/mytinydebugger/tdbg/build/debugging-examples/helloworld
7f9483434000-7f9483457000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 529041                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f9483656000-7f9483658000 rw-p 00022000 08:06 529041                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f9483658000-7f9483659000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff5a314000-7fff5a335000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff5a335000-7fff5a337000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff5a337000-7fff5a339000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

then focusing on the first address of the stack which is

```
7fff5a314000-7fff5a335000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack
```

and adding **0x7fff5a314000** + **0x400915** = 0x7FFF5A714915 and the same for
**0x40091a** . it worked for the first time as i expected but when i tried it again it doesn't work. i even automated doing this hex math in the code by fetching it from /proc/[helloworld pid]/maps automatically. it seems it works right for the first time and whatever i try again it doesn'.

I don't know why it doesn't work always.

***is my approach of setting a breakpoint by second trial is right?***

I am aware that i should place **INT3** instruction of intel at address i want to have the breakpoint. 
this is the code i use for setting the breakpoint.

```
void breakpoint::enable() {
    // Fetch the program instruction at the desired address of a specific process.
    auto data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, m_pid, m_addr, nullptr);
    // Save the lower byte which will be replaced with INT3 instruction.
    m_saved_data = static_cast<uint8_t>(data & 0xff);
    uint64_t int3 = 0xcc;
    // Set the lower byte to INT3 instruction
    uint64_t data_with_int3 = ((data & ~0xff) | int3);
    // Push the modified instruction with the breakpoint to the same address it was fetched.
    ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, m_pid, m_addr, data_with_int3);
    // Enable that (this) object of the class has a breakpoint at [m_addr] of [m_pid] process.
    m_enabled = true;
}
```

the full code of the debugger is [here](https://github.com/yahiafarghaly/tdbg). it is not big. it is simple with few commits as it is in its early age.

my OS is **ubuntu 14.04** and both the debugger and the helloworld example is compiled with **g++ 7.2.0**

Comment: It doesn't matter on Linux, but one obvious bug is that you should be doing `{PEEK,POKE}_TEXT` instead of `_DATA`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian it doesn't make a difference in Linux.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. It's still a bug though.

Comment: i mean changing {PEEK,POKE}_TEXT/DATA doesn't make a difference in context of linux.  read ptrace man page.

Comment: You are writing code that is *wrong* on non-Linux systems, and *currently* just happens to not be wrong on Linux. This is not a very smart approach, that's all I am saying. Generally you should strive to write *correct* code, especially when doing so costs you nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by restoring the instruction which was corrupted by INT3 instruction with other changes as showing in [my merge request](https://github.com/yahiafarghaly/tdbg/pull/2) in my repository.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should use `personality` with `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` to get predictable addresses, just like GDB does by default.  This will help you with figuring out what is going on.  You have not enabled PIE, though, so ASLR is not the cause of your difficulties for setting the breakpoint in the main program.

Then you need to check the result of the `ptrace` function for errors.  You need to set `errno` to zero before the call and check if it has changed afterwards.  This will tell you (within reason) whether you have passed a completely bogus address.

Also note that `ptrace` with `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` and `PTRACE_POKEDATA` always patches *complete* words.  In order to patch a single byte, you need to use shifts and masking operations to put the breakpoint instruction into the right byte within the word.

Comment: I tried personality i used it at my debugger start, is this the correct usage or i need to use before ptrace(peekdata,..)? but it doesn't help. i checked the error of ptrace, it returns me EIO when using trial 2. the trial 1 still fails with personallity or without.

Comment: You need to set the personality value before the `execve` system call which creates the new process.